# Cannot paste in comments of iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

I cannot paste in comments. The option appears on long press, but nothing is pasted when I tap it (the comment box blinks, but with no visible effect). Pasting in the answer box, question editing interface, etc. works, and in comments on the mobile site in a browser.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7
- OS Version: Version 11.0.3 (Build 15A432)